# Problems with GWT 2.4

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I compiled the version in svn tagged as gwt2.4rc. Now there are a
couple of more libraries than I had the last time. Are the any
instructions on which library is needed for what? I tried it with only
the standard libraries (servlet, servlet-deps, user) but I get the
following error when a requestfactory call is made:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.WeakMapping.setWeak(Ljava/lang/
Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)

I tried declaring the requestfactory-client and requestfactory-server
jars as dependencies, but i doesn't help. I am using maven to manage
my dependencies.
I would go back to 2.4 beta, but I need the drag&drop features that
were introduced later.
Does anybody has an idea what could be wrong? or any hints how i can
dig deeper into this? I spend a lot of time trying to figure this out
but without any success :(
Do I need to provide more information?

Regards,
arne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you deployed the 2.4-rc1 gwt-servlet.jar in your war/WEB-INF/lib ? Also, make sure you override the SDK for the gwt-maven-plugin: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/using-different-gwt-sdk-version.html

That being said:

- when using Maven, you shouldn't use gwt-servlet-deps but instead reference org.json:json and javax.validation:validation-api
- requestfactory-server can be used instead of gwt-servlet if you only use RequestFactory on the server-side (no GWT-RPC, no SafeHtml, no RegExp, etc.); requestfactory-client is to be used for Java clients (such as Android), not the case here.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thank you very much!!

The problem was that I had a different gwt-version in my gwt-maven-plugin. 
I have some gwt2.2 libraries in the lib folder because of some other dependencies(gin and gwtquery). 
I just removed the gwt-version and now it works :) When I try to declare the version I compiled myself as a dependency I get the message, that it cannot be found in the central-repository.
 I didn't find any information on how to add my own repository to the list where the plugin is searching. 
Can you tell me where to find this? 

Regards and Thank you again!
 arne

Comment: Hey Thomas, I was a little early to cheer. Running into a new error now as soon as I deploy the application into a tomcat. I opened a new thread, since I wasn't sure if this is connected somehow: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667806/problem-running-a-gwt-2-4-app-on-tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667806/problem-running-a-gwt-2-4-app-on-tomcat) Could the gwt-maven-plugin configuration be the problem? regards arne